# Fix a corrupted python environment?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

my computer froze during a anaconda update and now it's not working

I've tried to reinstall conda using 
conda install
and updating all the packages using  conda update --all

NO SUCCESS

In the terminal I get this response.

```
C:\Users\USER>conda update --all
An unexpected error has occurred.
Please consider posting the following information to the
conda GitHub issue tracker at:

    https://github.com/conda/conda/issues



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 573, in conda_exception_handler
    return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 92, in _main
    p, sub_parsers = generate_parser()
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 51, in generate_parser
    from ..cli import conda_argparse
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .common import add_parser_help
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\common.py", line 22, in <module>
    from ..resolve import MatchSpec
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\resolve.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .logic import Clauses, minimal_unsatisfiable_subset
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\logic.py", line 32, in <module>
    import pycosat
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycosat'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py", line 5, in <module>
    sys.exit(conda.cli.main())
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 164, in main
    return conda_exception_handler(_main, *args)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 589, in conda_exception_handler
    print_unexpected_error_message(e)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 543, in print_unexpected_error_message
    info_stdout, info_stderr = get_info()
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 502, in get_info
    from conda.cli import conda_argparse
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .common import add_parser_help
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\common.py", line 22, in <module>
    from ..resolve import MatchSpec
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\resolve.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .logic import Clauses, minimal_unsatisfiable_subset
  File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\logic.py", line 32, in <module>
    import pycosat
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycosat'
```

I expected to be able to reinstall or something good

Comment: Maybe you will have to delete conda manually and then install it

Comment: it might be worth trying `conda install pycosat` and running the other conda commands again.

Comment: Is there a `pycosat` in `C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\`?  Also, maybe you can share the last transaction that happened. E.g., show us the most recent section from `C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\conda-meta\history`.